# In a horizontal nav bar, how do I indentify the list items that goes to a second line because they will not fit in one line?

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal navigation bar with ten first level links. They all line up nicely when viewed on a browser that's at least 1200px in width. When the browser gets narrower than 1200px, the list begins to wrap to a second line. This breaks the appearance of my design (aesthetically). As a temporary fix to this, I gave the containing div for the navigation bar a fixed height, width set to 100%, and overflow set to hidden, such that the list items that gets wrapped to second line will not show.

Here's what I want to happen, and I hope you guys can help me with. I want the list items that goes to second line and gets hidden to be cloned and appended to another unordered list. For example, if link 10 goes to a second line, I want it cloned and appended to the .dropdown unordered list. If link 9 and link 10 go to a second line, I want them both cloned and appended to the .dropdown unordered list.

```
<div id="main-nav">
<ul class="horizontal">
<li id="one">link 1</li>
<li id="two">link 2</li>
<li id="three">link 3</li>
<li id="four">link 4</li>
<li id="five">link 5</li>
<li id="six">link 6</li>
<li id="seven">link 7</li>
<li id="eight">link 8</li>
<li id="nine">link 9</li>
<li id="ten">link 10</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="extra-nav">
<a href="#">Menu</a>

<ul class="dropdown">
<!-- this unordered list is initially empty, and will be populated by list items from main-nav -->
</ul>

</div>
```

Specifically, my questions are:

1. How do I find out if a list item goes to a second line, for example if #nine and #ten go to a second line because the whole horizontal nav does not fit the width of the containing div?
2. How do I add a custom class (ie .dropdown-item) to each list item (ie link 10
  ) only if they go to a second line (as in question 1)?
3. How do I clone those items given the custom class .dropdown-item and append those to ?

Answer (score 2):

you could use [JQuerys position function](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and [height function](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

By iterating through each nav link, you could check if any of them have a y position below the  height of the first link (assuming the first link always stays on the top line).

All of the links that are below that line could then be modified in whatever way.  It would look something like so

```
var bottom_of_first_line = $('#one').height();
$('#main-nav li').each( function() {
   if($(this).position().top <= bottom_of_first_line)
   {   //move it or remove it or whatever  }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! That led me to the right direction. I made a correction to your code, though. Instead of using <=, I changed it to >= for it to work properly. Here's the modified code, with the addition of cloning and appending: $(document).ready(function(){
var bottom_of_first_line = $('#main-nav #one').height();
$('#main-nav li').each(function() {
   if($(this).position().top >= bottom_of_first_line)
   {$(this).clone().appendTo('#dropdown')};
});
});